# Subprocess python module issue when taking input from file

Tags: python, subprocess

I am creating a python script for running the linux command which is " snmpwalk -v2c -c aL1walsh0aL <> ifInError"

I need to execute the command for multiple hosts IP which is in hostname.txt file.

When i run the python script below i am getting the output for "snmpwalk -v2c -c aL1walsh0aL" and the error for hostname not defined.
So basically my complete command is not executing which gives me correct output.

But i need the output for eg: snmpwalk -v2c -c aL1walsh0aL 10.0.0.1 ifInError

My python script:

```
import subprocess
with open("hostname.txt","rw") as f:
     for line in f.readlines():
         subprocess.Popen(['snmpwalk', '-v2c','-c',line],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
f.close()
```

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve]). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: Give us an example line or two from `hostname.txt`.

Comment: My hostaname.txt file contents are: 
10.0.2.5
10.5.2.4

Comment: Any suggetions on this ?

Answer (score 0):

---

```
import subprocess
with open("mac.txt","rw") as f: # mac.txt is the text file with mac address
     for line in f.readlines():
         print (line)
         print ("************")
         process=subprocess.Popen(['macsearch', line],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
         out=process.communicate() """ using process.communicate to save the 
output."""
         for o in out:
             print o
             print ('\n')
```

Comment: Please use code boxes around your code. Read this [meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51144/how-do-i-post-code-in-stackoverflow) for more details.